# gdrive web ui created folders not visible to API

Tags: python, api, google-drive-api

I setup API access to the gdrive API:
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python

Now I can see files with my python script that the python script creates, but not content created by me on the gdrive via web ui:
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files

Why/how do I share the entire gdrive with the python script? I don't see a service account associated with it.

Example of request:

```
def google_gdrive_search_folder(service_gdrive):
page_token = None
while True:
    response = service_gdrive.files().list(spaces='drive', fields='nextPageToken, files(id, name)', pageToken=page_token).execute()
    for file in response.get('files', []):
        # Process change
        print('Found file: %s (%s)' % (file.get('name'), file.get('id')))
    page_token = response.get('nextPageToken', None)
    if page_token is None:
        break
```

Or:

```
def google_gdrive_search_folder(service_gdrive):
    # Call the Drive v3 API
results = service_gdrive.files().list(pageSize=30, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
items = results.get('files', [])

if not items:
    print('No files found.')
else:
    print('Files:')
    for item in items:
        print(u'{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))
```

Comment: Hi ! I can create folders and files in the UI of the Drive and then following the Python Quickstart list them. **Could you please share a sample of your code so that I can see where your issue might be?** Also, note that in [the Quickstart example](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python) you have the parameter [pageSize](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list#parameters) which sets the amount of files and folders to display; if you increase it, it will show you more. Did this solve your issue?

Comment: @MateoRandwolf thank you for the response. I have shared a sample of what I am using in the question now. Changing the pagesize does not result in a difference. I only see folders created by the script, nothing create through the Web UI

Comment: Hi ! I have tried reproducing this again with your piece of code and I get the expected outputs. Are you the owner of this drive account ? Are you using [a service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts)? **Could you please try to retrieve the information of one of the files or folders that you created in the web UI that you cannot list** using [GET](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) to see if you are able to do so? Thanks ! :D